# Suppress the transpose of a symbol in sympy output when the symbol is a scalar

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, symbolic-math

I am trying to do some symbolic calculations in python using sympy. I therefore define some scalar and matrix symbols. However, the print output in the console looks rather ugly, I want to have it more compact. More specific, I have a scalar symbol `dt`, which is plugged into a matrix `Fd`. If I print the transpose of `Fd`, the entries containing `dt` are printed as `transpose(dt)`. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from sympy import *

dt = Symbol('dt')

A = MatrixSymbol('A',3,3)
B = MatrixSymbol('B',3,3)
C = MatrixSymbol('C',3,3)
D = MatrixSymbol('D',3,3)
E = MatrixSymbol('E',3,3)
F = MatrixSymbol('F',3,3)
Ct = MatrixSymbol('Ct',3,3)
I = Identity(3)
O = ZeroMatrix(3,3 )

Fd = BlockMatrix([[I, dt*I, A, B, -Ct*(dt*dt)/2], [O, I, C, D, -Ct*dt], [O, O, E, F, O], [O, O, O, I, O], [O, O, O, O, I]])
print "======================="
print "Fd = "
print Fd
print "======================="

Fdt = Fd.T
print "======================="
print "Fdt = "
print Fdt
print "======================="
```

And this is the output:

```
=======================
Fd = 
Matrix([
[I, dt*I, A, B, (-dt**2/2)*Ct],
[0,    I, C, D,      (-dt)*Ct],
[0,    0, E, F,             0],
[0,    0, 0, I,             0],
[0,    0, 0, 0,             I]])
=======================
=======================
Fdt = 
Matrix([
[                        I,                    0,  0, 0, 0],
[                  (dt*I)',                    I,  0, 0, 0],
[                       A',                   C', E', 0, 0],
[                       B',                   D', F', I, 0],
[(-transpose(dt)**2/2)*Ct', (-transpose(dt))*Ct',  0, 0, I]])
=======================
```

I want to have a more compact output (since I will do some more matrix multiplications), where `dt` is actually recognized as a scalar symbol (and therefore no transpose is printed). Does anybody have a clue how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, a generic sympy object is not known to be equal to its transpose. If you want dt to be treated as a real or complex scalar, declare it to be such:

```
dt = Symbol('dt', real=True)
```

or

```
dt = Symbol('dt', complex=True)
```

Then you'll have `dt` instead of `transpose(dt)` in the output.

Reference: [assumptions](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#module-sympy.core.assumptions)

Comment: Indeed, setting `complex=True` makes it work. This seems like undesired behavior. I [opened an issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/10959) for it.